# htaccess remove segment from url and redirect to https and www

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-deployer

I am deploying a Craft CMS site to a shared hosting account using Deployer.

The latest deployment is accessible from domain.com/current/public

My .htaccess file looks like the following, which strips current/public from the url and forces https:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ current/public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

I now need to also redirect all urls to use www

How can I adjust my .htaccess to force www on all urls?

*** UPDATE ***

I have managed to solve the above with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ current/public/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When I go to **example.com/admin** it redirects to **example.com/current/public/admin**. How can I adjust my htaccess file to remove 'current/public' from admin urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `http->https` and `www` adding rule should be top most rule so that it works on original URI instead of a rewritten URI due to other rule.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ current/public/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to clear browser cache before testing this rule.

Also add this redirect rule in `/current/public/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /current/public/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested your rule and it works fine for public urls, but when accessing the /admin section the current/public segment is still not removed.

Comment: Yep, and also tried in other browsers and computers

Comment: /admin is a 302 redirect. The page that loads with a 200 status is /current/public/admin/login. Potentially a built in redirect with Craft CMS admin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217336/discussion-between-pedro-and-anubhava).